# Linking a word in an Access record to Access record in another database

Tags: database, ms-access

Is there a way to link a word n any access record to another record entirely?

As an example, if I have a database of companies and one company, let's say Intel, has n its record that its customers are Microsoft and Apple. Can the words Microsoft and Apple in the record/table be linked to their respective records in another table in the database? And what about another database entirely?

Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link your table from your other database to your current database.  Then, do an inner join on the field that has Microsux or Crapple in it.  You can treat that table the same way you would treat any table that exists in your database.